# AppleScript check for string value in input

Tags: applescript

new to applescript and this small check is driving me nuts.

I want to check if the input to the script has the substring of "mob".
If i create a varible with mob1234, It works and returns true.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set testString to "mob1234"
    display dialog {"MOB" is in testString}

    return input
end run
```

If i change it to use the input, and set the input to mob1234, it fails and gives me false

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set testString to input
    display dialog {"MOB" is in testString}

    return input
end run
```

I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer given by iayork seems to be right, here some follow up:

```
-- When this is saved as compiled script one can call it from Terminal like: 
-- `osascript scriptName.scpt MOBstringArg1 arg2`

on run {input, parameters}
    if (input's class is list) then set input to (item 1 of input) as text

    if "MOB" is in input then
        display notification "FOUND MOB" with title "In: " & input
    end if

    return input
end run
```

See comment from iayork about calling a script with `osascript`.

Comment: osascript takes input here as a string, not a list, so this doesn't completely test the issue.  But doing the check to see if input is a list or not is a good idea and makes the script much more versatile.

Comment: Thanks running this as an automator service.  wish i could check mark both

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you're invoking your script.  If you're calling the script via Automator, be aware that in this mode input is a list, not a string, so this should work:

```
set testString to item 1 of input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just coerce the input to text directly when you assign it to testString: `set testString to input as text`, that is, if you aren't going to use any other list item of input.

Comment: The result of "{1, "item2", 3} as text" is "1item23" so this won't work unless the list has only one item.

Comment: Well, I wrote apparently 'as you aren't going to use any other list item of input.', I meant really 'if  you aren't going to use any other list item of input'. A string input isn't spread over several items of input, (but I guess paragraphs does, that is, 1 item per paragraph).